# Is it possible to hide the recognized devices in “WHERE YOU’RE LOGGED IN” section on facebook?

Tags: account-security, facebook

I am logged in to my husband’s facebook account. Is it possible that I can hide my device on his phone so that he won’t notice that I am logged in there? In the “Where you’re logged in” section, there are the list of devices. Is there any way I can hide my device and still logged in on his account?

Answer (score 2):

No - the *purpose* of the list is to show active sessions, so that the account owner can discover (and de-authenticate) rogue sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer